# Obfuscating classes that contain annotations

Tags: java, annotations, obfuscation

When obfuscating .class files annotations are removed. Is there a way to obfuscate these files(files containing annotations) without removing them. Is there a way to obfuscate non compiled .java files to preserve annotations, if it's possible?

---

How does java compiler treat annotations and where are they preserved? why after obfuscation all the annotations are removed. Can't I, after obfuscating the classes, bring back the annotations and put them back in their place in order to work?

Comment: What tool are you using? What are you trying to do? Why would you need to obfuscate `.java` files, and not a `.class`?

Comment: I am using proguard for example, and when I obfuscate with it, all the annotations are removed. so I am thinking of changing something on it so that it will not remove annotations from the files.

Comment: Different obfuscators will do different things to the generated bytecode. Since annotated classes have runtime retention, much of that information is stored in the bytecode. Whether the obfuscator does anything additional to this information is, I'm _guessing_, part of the obfuscator contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked and researched on annotations and obfuscation and I've found the following:

1. Annotations are kept in the meta section of the class byte-code
   and it's very hard to manipulate them. Obfuscation programs don't deal with such classes
2. I have tried a lot of obfuscators - commercial and opensource
   ones, but neither of them could obfuscate annotated classes that have
   all of their fields and methods annotated
3. The only way left that I could think of is to use xml configured
   files instead of annotations

Answer (score 0):

We generally obfuscated already compiled classes with [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#) and I am kind of sure, it's not possible to obfuscate non compiled .java files, since it's working on the byte-code itself.

To keep your annotations, you can tell proguard to keep specific attributes like annotations. You can find more information in their [example chapter](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#annotations). I recommend using proguardGui to build your own configuration file for the obfuscation-process.

Comment: Yes I know all about this, but the problem is that my project uses spring annoations and extensively. If I want to keep all the annotated classes, methods, attributes, there will be nothing to obfuscate, so I need to find a way on these annotations thing.

Comment: That wasn't really clear in your first statement. As far as I know (and I only have marginal proguard / obfuscation experience) you can keep those annotations and still obfuscate these classes. Afterwards the problem is, that he still won't find these classes, because (and thats just a guess) you have mapped them within a xml configuration and he cant find them by introspection anymore. One solution to work around this might be a programatically mapping of your beans, so you wont have to map these classes by string literals, but thats all just a guess, dont have any experience on that topic.